# computer freezing randomly

Tags: windows-7, freeze

Hi I have a computer under windows 7 32 bit and I randomly encounter freezing :

the pointer does not move anymore, nothing happens and the light indicating that the RAM is being used
 is off. I have to force rebooting.  Can
 the freezes be because of a virus, although avast free version does not find anything,  malwarebyte anti malware find a few thing (bitool.DLL)

EDIT :

I checked my logs and I find just before the unexpected reboot a message indicating that the driver has detected an error on the controller `\Device\Harddisk2\DR2`

EDIT 2:

CrystalDiskInfo doesn't display any error, everything is good according to it. And I have only a disk 0 and 1 no #2.

Comment: I've never seen a computer with a RAM activity light; that would be on *constantly* while the computer is on. Do you mean the disk activity light? Does the same thing happen e.g. if you let it just sit in the BIOS setup? Does it happen if you boot Windows in fail-safe mode? Random freezes can often be related to overheating; is the CPU and GPU cooling system working properly (including actual heat transfer from the die; check the temperature of both with appropriate diagnostic tools)?

Comment: In the event that this is not virus related, which softwares do you have installed?

Comment: Localised to a misplaced wire, not really transferable

Comment: @guisasso various programs, including a No CD patch for Assassin's Creed because it took too long to load from the CD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found i ! It was because of a wire squeezed in the Fan. Thanks anyway!

Comment: why down vote ?

Comment: A wire squeezed in the fan? Could you at least elaborate? The fan slowed to a halt because of the wire and so something was overheating? The CPU fan... the what? You need to remember that your question is an archived piece of information others may use to solve their own similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

most time a pc freezes randomly and there is not really a system behind it.
then the ram is the source of the trouble. also if there is no light indicating that it is used (light flashes if used extrem) normal useage just flashes this fast u can't even see it.

also it is possible that the light doesn't be light cause the ram isn't propper attached.

you should better not count on that light better use a ram check tool!!!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a bad hard drive. Go to "my computer" and right click on the hard disk, go to tools, run a disk scan. Or whichever way you prefer.

Many times I've seen the random freezing like you are seeing be caused by a failing hard drive.

Back up any important data ASAP.

Comment: I used TuneUp Utilities's, and it didn't found anything